# SQL filter from range expression like used in Dynamics Ax 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, axapta

While working with queries in Microsoft Dynamics Ax 2012 (and other versions) you can specify a range like `'B*, D..H, !F*'`.

Using above range on column 'column1' in table 'table1', we can expect the same result as the following where-clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE column1 LIKE 'B%'
OR (column1 >= 'D' AND column1 <= 'H')
AND column1 NOT LIKE 'F%'
```

I now need to get the same query result using T-SQL (SQL Server). The ranges I want to apply are stored in a table and can be user modified, so in some way the filter has to be applied during runtime.

If possible to achieve above in SQL Server 2012 that is preferrable.

Trying to solve above I started by replacing all `*` with `%`, splitting string (`STRING_SPLIT` is not supported in SQL Server 2012 but may be implemented as a function) by commas. Then in some way insert result into temporary table, and using the temporary table with a EXISTS SELECT. However, this turns out to be too complicated for me.

Does anyone have an elegant solution to this?

**EDIT:**
MS Dynamics AX converts the range, which is applied to a column, into the WHERE-clause using OR between each comma separated part in the range, except when it is a negation ('!'), in which case AND is used instead. The '..' part is converted to '>=' AND '<='.

Simple example:

```
table1
id   column1
==   =======
1    Apple
2    Banana
3    Fruit
4    Date
```

applying above example range on 'column1' would result in following:

```
table1
id   column1
==   =======
2    Banana
4    Date
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data.desired results and your attempt

Comment: T-SQL is *not* the tool for parsing a string like `'B*, D..H, !F*'` into multiple boolean clauses in the `WHERE`; you need to use some kind of language to parse that. Not to mention if you *had* to do it in T-SQL (again **don't**), you would have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: What's the logic that creates OR vs AND, or how does the hypotethical TSQL code knows where it should be OR and AND from your example filter as well as how does it know which column name it should use

Comment: Can your clauses *only* be (single) letters as well, or could you have something like `'10..110'` or `'*Hotel,!Florida*'`?

Comment: 1) AX 2012 is way, way past its End of Support date. 2) Those "ranges" are translated to SQL by AX itself. Why do you want to replicate the functionality? *It matters a lot*. AX itself won't try to parse and filter all 50M transaction rows, it will translate the ranges to more efficient queries or use lookup tables, that allow the use of indexes 3) AX delays are typically caused by unfortunate implementer queries that can't use indexes. If you try to generate a `LIKE` pattern from these wildcards you'll end up scanning all 50M rows and blocking every other user

Comment: BTW guess how I know delays are cause by bad implementer code .... That `column1 NOT LIKE 'F%'` for example will be *very* slow even with an index, because it matches *all* rows except those that start with `F`. If you want to generate reports over transactional data, *extract* that data into a reporting database incrementally, instead of trying to scan the entire database every time. The AX 2012 docs explain how to set up and use OLAP cubes for reporting

Comment: @ThomA, yes, you could use '10..110' as the interval, which would give >= 10 and <= 110.

Comment: @ThomA, the second part of the example range specifies D..H, and thus values beginning with F would be included. The third '!F*'  excludes these values.

Comment: Ahh, so then we need to know how you know it should be `OR` or `AND`, as @siggemannen [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77785820/sql-filter-from-range-expression-like-used-in-dynamics-ax-2012?noredirect=1#comment137129353_77785820)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes, I know, Dynamics Ax 2012 is old and should be replaced. As part of the transition to a new system we need a new software for hand scanners, so that the Business Connector can be retired. The ranges are used to filter a table in Ax to show the warehouse personal valid items, and if possible to use in SQL that would be easiest, so that the original Ax functionality remains the same(reluctant to make changes to such an old system). Please note that the ranges are used to filter a few lines only, so  performance is no less importance

Comment: @PatrikChristiansson, you're not working at OJ by any chance? :D This issue sounds very close to home =)

Comment: Why are you querying the database then, instead of generating reports or using APIs? Whatever you do *now*, will most likely be discarded anyway. The current version is D365 for Finance, a cloud-first offering, with REST APIs, Power BI reporting, Power Apps connectors etc

Comment: @ThomA, Dynamics Ax replaces the ',!' with AND NOT, and ',' with OR. An interval like A..C is transformed into column1 >= A AND column1 <= C. If we ignore interval/'..' case, is there a way to implement something like "LIKE IN" and use that on the split range string?

Comment: I can think of ways, but in 2012, it's a far worse position; solution I went down, for an experiment, uses `STRING_SPLIT` (with ordinal), `GENERATE_SERIES`, `STRING_AGG`, `TRIM`, you have *none* of those tools.

Comment: Best solution is to construct dynamic SQL. You don't need a temp table, you can do the `EXISTS` directly in dynamic SQL. But you are wasting your time on 2012, it has far too many missing features. Maybe use Powershell, Python or C# to construct the dynamic query?

Comment: Ok, understand. It is more likely more effort to use these Ax-ranges in normal SQL than can be motivated, and we look into other workarounds. Thank you all for your kind assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a potential solution that should work in sql server 2012:

```sql
DECLARE @colName SYSNAME = 'test'
SELECT  STUFF((
        SELECT  prefix + prefix2 + @colname + ' ' + CASE WHEN btw = 1 THEN '>=' when lke = 1 then 'LIKE' else '=' END + ' ''' + replace(data_left, '*', '%') +'''' 
        +   CASE WHEN btw = 1 
                THEN ' AND ' + @colname + ' <= ' +  '''' +REPLACE(data_right, '*', '%')  + ''''
                ELSE ''
            END + postfix1
        FROM    (
            SELECT  CASE WHEN n.neg = 1 THEN ' AND NOT ' ELSE '  OR ' END AS prefix
            ,   '(' AS prefix2
            ,   CASE WHEN btw = 1 THEN LEFT(dataFixed, charindex('..', dataFixed) - 1) ELSE dataFixed END AS data_left
            ,   CASE WHEN btw = 1 THEN stuff(dataFixed, 1, charindex('..', dataFixed) + 1, '') END AS data_right
            ,   ')' AS postfix1
            ,   lke
            ,   btw
            ,   id
            FROM    (
                    SELECT  RTRIM(LTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'))) DATA
                    ,   Split.a.value('let $n := . return count(../*[. << $n]) + 1', 'int') AS id
                    FROM
                    (
                        SELECT  CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(x.s, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
                        
                    ) AS A
                    CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)
                ) data
            CROSS apply (
                    SELECT  CASE WHEN LEFT(data, 1) = '!' THEN  1 ELSE 0 END AS neg
                    ,   CASE WHEN data LIKE '%*%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS lke
                    ,   CASE WHEN data LIKE '%..%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS btw
                    ,   case when LEFT(data, 1) = '!' then stuff(data, 1, 1, '') else data end as dataFixed
                ) n
            ) x
        ORDER BY id
        FOR xml path(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 5, '')
from (
    VALUES  (N'B*, DB..HB, !F*')
    ,   (N'B*, DB*')
    ,   (N'!B')
    ,   (N'!B*')
    ,   (N'!BZZ..ZZABC')
) x(s)
```

Outputs:

| s | (column 2) |
| --- | --- |
| B*, DB..HB, !F* | (test LIKE 'B%') OR (test >= 'DB' AND test <= 'HB') AND NOT (test LIKE 'F%') |
| B*, DB* | (test LIKE 'B%') OR (test LIKE 'DB%') |
| !B | NOT (test = 'B') |
| !B* | NOT (test LIKE 'B%') |
| !BZZ..ZZABC | NOT (test >= 'BZZ' AND test <= 'ZZABC') |

The basic building blocks are:

1. data subquery splits a string by "," and generates a id counter, this is equivalent to STRING_SPLIT with a counter parameter in sql server 2022. If you have some special chars in your strings, like <>, you might have to replace them before splitting by this method, since it uses xml
2. the `n` cross apply generates flags that controls what kind of string it is, for example negative, like, between and also returns a unnegated string
3. The rest pretty much concats together the strings and handles correct AND / OR prefixes
4. Finally, FOR XML generates the proper final strings

Comment: This is a very good solution, thank you! I have built a dynamic sql query based on above and it works like charm.